# How to set a "First Word Hotkey" to button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hotkeys

**Situation:** I have a HTML Form, inside it, i have some `<input>`'s with some info, and a `<input type=submit>` that is the Send button, who sends the form content to the url set on action parameter.

**Problem:** Missing knowledge(i don't know how to do).

**Explanation of what i want:** I want a hotkey like, for example, hit now on your browser or another common software like Notepad the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key of your keyboard. You will see a menu coming down on the top of screen, and some Word that are underlined like this one:

[image: Alt menu]

Well, you see the **F** with a underline, and you know that if you hit the key <kbd>F</kbd> the **File** menu will be opened.

**Details:** The hotkey that i want, is a **little different from the example above**, but have the same concept. Because i want to allow the user to Press: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> instead of only <kbd>F</kbd> to automatically click on the Button that have **F** set as hotkey to itself.

This way, i can place one `<input id=F type=button>` i used attribute ID, for example, and if i press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> the button is automatically clicked.

In theory, maybe its easy, but i really do not know how to do this on Javascript.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: You've put hotkeys in your tags, so I'm not sure if you've seen the library [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)?

Comment: Hmm, thats interesting, `$(document).on('keypress', null, 'alt+f', fn);` works, but, i need to create a function to every single input that have hotkey? and bind one by one? and how i can underline the first word of a Button if the value do not accept html ? :p

Comment: @Wil Please, post a answer containing the jquery.hotkeys implementation and the answer's of the comments above, then i mark correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like

```
<input type="submit" accesskey="F"/>
```

Now, when the users hits <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on Firefox) it will be as though he had clicked on the submit button.

EDIT: to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> on firefox too see this topic: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=446830

> You can change it back to how it was using about:config, change:
>
> ui.key.chromeAccess to 5
>
> ui.key.contentAccess to 4

In Opera, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. That brings up the access key list for the current page. Then you can press any number from the access key list to follow the respective link. Users can change this keyboard shortcut under `Tools > Preferences > Mouse and keyboard`.

Comment: That sounds perfect, but unfortunately it do not worked here, i dont know why :(

Comment: +1 for the simplicity and elegancy of this solution, by the way, my question was using Alt + F only, because my target is user experience and the user of course do not want to use Alt + Shift + F sorry :p

Comment: Sadly that is browser controlled behaviour, if you want to be consistent I fear you'll have to go the javascript way, or convince all your users to use the same browser.

Comment: Yeah, browser controlled behaviours can never be edited. I know. By the way i have Google Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE10, and Firefox installed here and all of them have only `Alt` + `Shift` + `F` working... what browser you're using?

Comment: @PauloRoberto on Chrome 32 ALT + SHORTCUT works fine, also on IE 11, FF needs to use the SHIFT key too, but see my edit for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use [jQuery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) then you would bind each key or keystroke to a function and deal with it that way.

If you gave your buttons an ID of the key you want them to respond to, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $doc, altKeys, modified;
    $doc = $(document);
    modified = function (ev) {
        var selector;
        selector = '#' + ev.data.replace(/^alt\+/, '');
        $('button').css({background: 'transparent'});
        $(selector).css({background: 'red'});
    };
    $('button').each(function () {
        var key;
        k = $(this).attr('id');
        $doc.bind('keydown', 'alt+' + k, modified);
    }); 
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkDD6/) for a working example